# UIPanGestureRecognizer translationInView returning different values on iPhone/ipad

Tags: uiscrollview, uipangesturerecognizer

Hi I have this bit of code in my project,

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGPoint translation = [scrollView.panGestureRecognizer translationInView:scrollView];
    if(translation.x < 0.0f) {
        // Something
    }
}
```

and it works fine on iPhone, but for some reason on iPad, my CGPoint is always returning (0,0).
Any ideas as to why?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, and came up with a nasty workaround, using the `velocityInView()` method instead.  I don't have a real iPad, so I'm suspicious that the problem may actually be with the simulator.

Objective-C:

```swift
CGPoint velocity = [scrollView.panGestureRecognizer velocityInView: scrollView];
CGPoint translation = CGPointMake(velocity.x * 0.1, velocity.y * 0.1);
```

Swift:

```swift
let translation = scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.velocityInView(self) * 0.1
```

I'm using a very handy CGPoint extension you can find [right here.](https://github.com/raywenderlich/SKTUtils/blob/master/SKTUtils/CGPoint%2BExtensions.swift)

Comment: Necromancering your answer, but the problem arise on both ipad and simulator in my case.